# Printing out matrix in c++, class method problem

Tags: c++, matrix

I want to display a matrix using class and methods. Im getting "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\cc41EMS5.o:lab6.cpp:(.text+0x3d6): undefined reference to `Matrix::Matrix()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"  error. I guess its because of printMatrix method(that worked not as a method in main), but I dont know how to fix that.
Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int rowSize, int colSize);
    void setSize(int rowSize, int colSize);
    string printMatrix(int rowSize, int colSize);
    void free_data();
    void allocate_data();

private:
    int rowSize;
    int colSize;
    double **p;
    //vector<vector<int>> matrix(rowSize, vector<int>(colSize));
};

void Matrix::allocate_data() {
    p = new double *[rowSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
        p[i] = new double[colSize];
    }
}

void Matrix::free_data() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
        delete[] p[i];
    }
    delete[] p;
}

void Matrix::setSize(int rowSize, int colSize) {
    int newSize = 0;
    p[rowSize][colSize] = newSize;
}

Matrix::Matrix(int rowSize, int colSize) {
    this->rowSize = rowSize;
    this->colSize = colSize;
    allocate_data();
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
            p[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

string Matrix::printMatrix(int rowSize, int colSize) {
    int i, j;
    int matrix[i][j];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) //it worked in main, but doesn't in class
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
            0 >> matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Matrix" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    int rowSize;
    int colSize;
    cout << "Enter size of rows and columns: ";
    cout << "Rows: ";
    cin >> rowSize;
    cout << "Cols: ";
    cin >> colSize;

    Matrix m;

    m.printMatrix(rowSize, colSize);

    return 0;
}
```

Please send help

Comment: `0>>matrix[i][j];` what does this mean in line 73 ??

Comment: `Matrix::printMatrix` should be of `void` type because you aren't returning anything from it!

Answer (score 2):

You declare two constructors:

> ```
>    Matrix();
>    Matrix(int rowSize, int colSize);
> ```

But you define only one:

> ```
> Matrix::Matrix(int rowSize, int colSize)       
> {
>    this->rowSize=rowSize;
>    this->colSize=colSize;
>    allocate_data();
>    for(int i=0; i<rowSize; i++)
>    {
>        for(int j=0; j<colSize; j++)
>         {
>             p[i][j]=0;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

````
Furthermore, in `main` you call the constructor that you happened to not define:

> ```
> Matrix m;
> ```

Instead, get rid of the declaration for `Matrix::Matrix()` since you lack a definition, and use the constructor that takes two arguments:
````

int main()
{
int rowSize;
int colSize;
cout<<"Enter size of rows and columns: ";
cout<<"Rows: ";
cin>>rowSize;
cout<<"Cols: ";
cin>>colSize;

```
Matrix m(rowSize, colSize);

m.printMatrix(rowSize,colSize);
```

return 0;
}

```
## Additional improvements

You don't need to pass the size of the matrix to `Matrix::printMatrix`, since the matrix already has the size as members. By passing those parameters to `printMatrix`, you're making the class more confusing and error-prone to use. If I constructed a 3x3 matrix and tried to call `printMatrix(10,10)` on it, I would certainly invoke undefined behavior and likely crash the program.

Get rid of the parameters (in both definition and declaration) and use the existing `rowSize` and `columnSize` fields to control the loops in that function. The return type also ought to be `void`.

Also, `0 >> matrix[i][j];` makes no sense. The correct syntax is `matrix[i][j] = 0;`.
```

Answer (score 1):

You define and use a parameterless *Matrix* constructor (*Matrix();*) but you do not implement it.

You may either:

- Delete the *Matrix()* definition and use the constructor that you define (*Matrix m(rowSize, colSize);*)
- Implement the parameterless constructor, creating the matrix with some predefined values. You can use a *delegating constructor* to call the constructor that accepts parameters

  ```
  Matrix::Matrix() : Matrix(4,4) {
  }
  ```

I would recommend the first option